# Python - Generate a grid of equally spaced points

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I have an MxN area of squares where the ratio M:N is a:b. How do I algorithmically compute a series of (x,y) coordinates that correspond to the centres of these squares?

For example, a 2x2 grid of squares with a ratio 1:1 would have the following centres (if the width and height were 100):

```
(25,25),(75,25),(25,75),(75,75)
```

Example code:

```
x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])
M,N = 100,100

for a in range(1,M+1):
    for b in range(1,N+1):
        print(a,b)
        x = np.append(x,a)
        y = np.append(y,b)
```

Comment: How is it related to python ?

Comment: perhaps some input-output example, and/or code snippets, what you did already...

Comment: I think you have to figure that out on your own. Then if you have problems implementing your solution (that is, your code doesn't work as expected, or you get stuck on a very specific point), we can help you out.

Comment: So what's the **problem** with your attempt? Errors? Unexpected outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're given m,n and a height and width of the total area. Call the height and width i, j and observe that they must be multiples of m,n and that i/m = j/n or we exit with bad input. Call this quantity i/m (the side length of a square) s. It should be pretty obvious now that we just want 
`[(s/2) + (x * s) for x in range(m)]` for the first row. To extend this to a grid, we'd just do the obvious

```
[((s/2) + (x * s), (s/2) + (y * s)) for x in range(m) for y in range(n)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is neat!